# Post call from Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get an authentication token from an API. 
the request is supposed to look like

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: mysageone.ca.sageone.com

client_id=4b64axxxxxxxxxx00710&
client_secret=iNumzTxxxxxxxxxxhVHstrqWesH8tm9&
code=12a0f9c12cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx92a48cc1f237ead&
grant_type=authorization_code&
redirect_uri=https://myapp.com/auth/callback
```

My current code keeps giving me status 400. I have tried to modify the headers but it doesn't work. i have also tried to make the required parameters part of the path using ?.

```
const http = require('http');
    var options = {
      hostname: 'app.sageone.com',
      path: '/oauth2/token',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        "client_id":"xxxxx",
        "client_secret":"xxxxx",
        "code":"xxxxxx",
        "grant_type":"authorization_code",
        "redirect_uri":"https://some link"
        }
    };
    console.log('in users file point 2');
    var req1 = http.request(options, (res1) => {
      console.log('statusCode:', res1.statusCode);
      console.log('headers:', res1.headers);
      console.log('message',res1.statusMessage);
      res1.on('data', (d) => {
        res.json(d);
      });
    });

    req1.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error('error starts here',e);
    });
    req1.end();
});
```

Comment: Presumably your auth API is expected you to call it via https? If so, you need the [`https`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) package rather than the `http` one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your problem is not with Node.js, but with your use of Sage One's api. This is [the relevant documentation](https://developer.sageone.com/docs/en/v1) that might solve your problem.

From a quick glance it looks like you want to send a `GET` not a `POST`, and you should send those parameters in the URL. Here is the example URL they give:

https://www.sageone.com/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=4b64axxxxxxxxxx00710&redirect_uri=https://myapp.com/auth/callback   &scope=full_access

I've never used Sage One before, but that would match my experience with other OAuth APIs.

Comment: I have already completed the 1st step and have the code. I was trying to get the auth token mentioned in the documentation where I am stuck.